# Xcode 8.3, cursor auto jump up.

Tags: xcode

[image]

As you can see in the image. Cursor is jumped up and let highlighted current line below it . When i type text will appearance in highlight line . How can i fix it ? I didn't change anything setting in Xcode, it work normally yesterday but now it just happen.